# How long does web SQL data persist?

Tags: cordova, mobile, offline, web-sql

I'm starting to work on an hybrid application which rely on web sql capabilities. The application works with a local database (web SQL) which may be synchronized to a distant database if the device is online.

Off course, it is important for the application to be quickly available, and therefore to have its web SQL data available as long as possible without requiring online exchanges. More, some of the data will only be local, and should not be lost.

So far, I performed successful tests with Chrome for local/distant synchronization and offline mode. HTML5/JS files will be packaged with PhoneGap/Cordova for Android's and Apple's marketplaces.

So here are my questions :

- How long will web sql data remain available ?
- May the device be reboot ?
- What if a newer version of the app is installed ?
- Are there any specific practices I should be aware of, regarding websql persistence issues ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>How long will web sql data remain available ?
```

Until it is deleted by the application

```
>May the device be reboot ?
```

Yes

```
>What if a newer version of the app is installed ?
```

Existence checking of the database should be part of the installation process

```
>Are there any specific practices I should be aware of, regarding websql persistence issues?
```

* Future versions of SQLite may not be compatible with the current version

Answer (score 2):

Currently all browser databases are temporary storage, until quota management api available. So your data may lost at any time.